# Android - Ethernet - Programmatically

Tags: android, static, settings, ethernet, dhcp

I am developing an Android app which will be used by custom devices which will have ethernet support (and also wifi).

**The app has to enable a settings activity for Ethernet.**

*Please NOTE that these settings have to be run by the app and not by the Android settings, since the app will be the only thing running on the device and the user will not have access to the Android running in the background.*

**The user has to be able to:**

1. ENABLE/DISABLE Ethernet
2. Choose DHCP or STATIC
3. If choosing STATIC - set IP, gateway

The problem is that I cannot access the `android.net.ethernet` programmatically and there is no explanation about this issue online.

So if someone has done something like this, please help me get into the right direction.

Comment: I can only provide some links which may help: [android.net.ethernet](https://gitorious.org/0xdroid/frameworks_base/source/248edcc9f3ee2a69be568906af6ebad376817e47:ethernet/java/android/net/ethernet), [android ethernet tutorial](http://de.slideshare.net/gxben/elce-2012-dive-into-android-networking-adding-ethernet-connectivity)

Comment: Thanks. I was looking at this already few days ago but it did not help me any further :( since it was done for enterprise desktop ip phones and it used some frameworks i do not have or do not know how to use them

Comment: Same Problem... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21746192/ethernet-connectivity-through-programatically-android/21758581?noredirect=1#21758581

Comment: Someone wrote a library... Don't know if it works nor how complicated it is... https://github.com/gxben/aosp-ethernet

Comment: But how can i use that ? Means Should i run that or ? No means of idea regarding how to do with that ?

Comment: me neither, have no idea how to use that

Comment: here is a youtube presentation of that tutorial for enterprise desktop ip phone ... it gives some insights http://youtu.be/LwI2NBq7BWM

Comment: i have made a possible solution for this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21840573/1564910

Answer (score 5):

I know it is very late but it might help someone else.

I had some of the requirements you mentioned for my android application.
This is how I achieved some of the points

**1. ENABLE/DISABLE Ethernet**

//Enable Ethernet

```
 ifconfig eth0 up
```

//Disable Ethernet

```
 ifconfig eth0 down
```

**3. If chosen STATIC - set IP, gateway**

Fire these commands from java code.

```
su -c ifconfig eth0 172.19.10.105 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
route add default gw 172.19.10.2 dev eth0
```

You can execute these commands using following code.

Here `command` variable is one of the commands mentioned above.

```
                Process p;
                try {
                    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
                    p.waitFor();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

                    String line = "";
                    while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
                        output.append(line + "n");
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                String response = output.toString();
```

Comment: does this require root?